# Error opennig dialog JQuery in a table

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if($i++%2==0){
       $color="#FFFFFF";
    }else{
       $color="#CCCCCC";
    }

    ?>

    <tr bgcolor='<?php echo $color; ?>' onmouseover="this.style.background='#ABFB04';" onmouseout="this.style.background='<?php echo $color; ?>';">
    <?php

echo "<td class=tablelist>";

echo $row["ICAO"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Name"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["WeightEmpty"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["WeightFull"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["CargoFull"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Range"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Price"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["FirstClassSeats"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["BusinessClassSeats"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["EconomyClassSeats"]. '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo "<img class='editaircraft' src='./images/info.png'></td></tr>"; 

?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 425
        });

        $( ".editaircraft" ).click(function() {
            $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    }); 
</script>

<div id="editaircraftdialog" title="Edit Aircraft">
    <?php require_once('./edit_aircraft.php?icao=1'); ?> 
</div>

<?php
}

echo "</table>";
$pagination->render();
?>
```

It´s a table. But it only shows one line when It must be 3. If I delete the require once in the editaircraftdialog () it works fun. But I have other error, if i click in the info.png image I see the dialog but it shows me this errors:

> Warning: require_once(./edit_aircraft.php?icao=1): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\airvirtus\albrep\aircrafts_list.php on line 135
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   './edit_aircraft.php?icao=1' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\airvirtus\albrep\aircrafts_list.php on line 135

Comment: where is your file `edit_aircraft.php` and `aircrafts_list.php` located?

Comment: edit_aircraft.php and aircrafts_list.php are in same path/location?

Comment: congratulation.. u figured out where the error is.....

Comment: edit_aircraft.php and aircraft_list are in the same directory! The code in the question is from aircraft_list.

Comment: try removing `./` from `./edit_aircraft.php?icao=1` and check.
Check my answer below too

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the files `edit_aircraft.php` and `aircrafts_list.php` are located in same path/location.
If so, then change to:

```
 <?php require_once('edit_aircraft.php?icao=1'); ?>
```

Comment: the same and the file is in the same directory. I think is an error putting it on the wile but I don´t know

Comment: Warning: require_once(./edit_aircraft.php?icao=1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\airvirtus\albrep\aircrafts_list.php on line 135
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './edit_aircraft.php?icao=1' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\airvirtus\albrep\aircrafts_list.php on line 135
                                                                        And I only see one line in the table (the first one) and the next lines dont shows.

Comment: No, but the while don´t cotinue when it arrive in the require the while stops!